# GPT script forces scroll down to ad when # exists in url

Tags: javascript, html, double-click-advertising, google-publisher-tag

Does anyone else have this issue with the google publisher tags?

Whenever a hash exists in the URL, google publisher tags forces the page to scroll down to the ad when it loads, if the page is refreshed, it scrolls down to the ad and then jumps back up to the original location prior to being refreshed.

The script I'm using doesn't seem out of the ordinary.

Defining Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        googletag.cmd.push(function() {
            googletag
                .defineSlot('/site/test', [[300, 250]], 'gpt-ad-sto-300-250-0')
                .addService(googletag.pubads())
                .setTargeting('sec', 'Home')
                .setTargeting('pos', 'sto');

            googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
            googletag.enableServices();
        });
    </script>
```

Ad location:

```
<div id="gpt-ad-sto-300-250-0">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('gpt-ad-sto-300-250-0'); });
        </script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly same issue today and only solution I found to fix this is to remove hash from url.